# How can I render the values ​of an array in sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-storage

Hi everyone I'm using sessionStorage to save some tasks of my todo App, each of these has a dynamically generated key and I would like to bring all the values ​​back to my page.
I tried everything and asked many people, can anyone tell me how I can do it ??
Below is the example code...

```
let obj = Object.keys(sessionStorage)
  let get_obj = obj.map((el)=> {return el;})
 sessionStorage.getItem(get_obj)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more, on what do you want to achieve? and what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I don't understand either.  If you want to store an array in sessionStorage then you must convert it to a string first.  Try to JSON encode it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of work, I found the solution ...
The following must be done:

```
        Object.keys(sessionStorage).map((el,i)=>{
            let num = sessionStorage.getItem(el)
            return(
            <Task
            key={i}
            value={num}
            />
            )
        })
```